# emitting data from chiled to parent using vue.js and laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-directives

i new in `vue.js`  i have test component  is child and showdata component  is parent   my proplem is when i emit data from child to parent  it is emitted successfully but when i show data in parent by `@click="showusersdata1(listdata.id)`   i get empty data like attached image   so how to    show user data 
here is my code 
showdata.vue

```
<template>
        <div>


            id={{setUserData.id}},
            name={{setUserData.name}}
            email={{setUserData.email}}
            <test v-on:showusersdata1="userData($event)"></test>


        </div>
</template>


<script>

    import MyHome from "./home";
   // let Test=require('./components/test.vue').default
    import test from "./test"
    export default {

        // components: {MyHome},
        name: "showData",
        data:function () {
            return{
                setUserData:{}
            }
        },
        components:{
            test

        },
        methods:{
            userData:function (passedata) {
            console.log(passedata)
           //  this.setUserData={}
                this.setUserData= this.setUserData.push(passedata)

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

test.vue

```
<template>
    <div  class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
<h1>this is test components1</h1>
            <!-- List group -->
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group" id="myList" role="tablist">

                <a  v-for  ="(listdata,key) in list"  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  active" data-toggle="list" href="#home" role="tab">
                    <ul class="test">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                        <i  @click="showusersdata1(listdata.id)" class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                    </ul> {{listdata.name}}</a>



            </div>


        </div>
        <h1>this is cchiled show data coponent</h1>


    </div>

</template>


<script>





    import ShowData from "./showdata";

    export default {

        name: "Test",
        components:{
            ShowData

        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                list:{},
                errors:{},


            }
        },

        mounted(){
            axios.post('/getAllData')
                // .then((response) =>this.list=response.data )
                .then((response) =>{
                    this.list=response.data

                } )

                .catch((error) =>this.errors=error.response.data.errors )

        },
        methods:{
            showusersdata1:function (key) {
              var index = this.list.find( ({ id }) => id == key );

                this.$emit('userData', index)
            }
        }




    }
</script>
<style scoped>
    .test{
        float:right
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are emiting here:

`this.$emit('userData', index)`

Which means the name of your event is `'userData'`. That's what you have to listen to in the parent. But if you check your parent, you are listening to the event like this:

`v-on:showusersdata1="userData($event)"`

This means you are trying to listen to the `'showusersdata1'` event, which is not fired. **You are confusing the method name in your child for your event name**. Instead of what you did, you can listen to your event like this:

`v-on:userData="userData"`

It's also kind of a convention to name event listeners by adding "on" in front of them, example:

- event name is `'userDataReceived'`
- event listener would be `onUserDataReceived`

Comment: please  help me with mpore details wher is the error and how to fix

Comment: i change don:userData="userData(payload)" but i dosent work

Comment: Does your parent userData method log something in the console when you emit ?

Comment: after chang i found this error       Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: setUserData is not defined"

Comment: Okay I see, that's another problem, but not related to the event anymore. Event is now successfully emited and handler is called. Are you able to investigate this further now ?

Comment: when ichanged  on:userData="userData(payload)"  i get error pay load is not defiend

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I didn't notice. Use `v-on:userData="userData"`